# How to fix ' Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile /root/.sbt/launchers/1.2.8/sbt-launch.jar'

Tags: docker, predictionio

I was following the tutorial [Apache PredictionIO Docker](https://github.com/apache/predictionio/blob/develop/docker/README.md#run-predictionio-with-selectable-docker-compose-files).When I was the step "Build Template"

```sh
# pio-docker build --verbose
```

It went an error.

```sh
[root@docker01 MyRecommendation]# pio-docker build --verbose
[INFO] [Engine$] Using command '/usr/share/predictionio/sbt/sbt' at /templates/MyRecommendation to build.
[INFO] [Engine$] If the path above is incorrect, this process will fail.
[INFO] [Engine$] Uber JAR disabled. Making sure lib/pio-assembly-0.13.0.jar is absent.
[INFO] [Engine$] Going to run: /usr/share/predictionio/sbt/sbt  package assemblyPackageDependency in /templates/MyRecommendation
[ERROR] [Engine$] Error: Invalid or corrupt jarfile /root/.sbt/launchers/1.2.8/sbt-launch.jar
[ERROR] [Engine$] Return code of build command: /usr/share/predictionio/sbt/sbt  package assemblyPackageDependency is 1. Aborting.
[root@docker01 MyRecommendation]#
```

1.I've made the dirs

```
/templates/MyRecommendation
```

,I don't know some how why the command

```sh
pio-docker
```

,always need that dirs,nor the next dirs

```
templates/MyRecommendation
```

.My current dirs is

```
/root/predictionio/docker/templates/MyRecommendation
```

to execute the command

```sh
# pio-docker build --verbose
```

2.

```sh
/usr/share/predictionio/sbt/sbt
```

That file do not exists,before I made a softlinks to it.now  if I execute it ,it works fine.In the original tutorial

```
Installing with Docker
```

,it didn't tell you to do it .

Comment: I've got it!!!I enter the dirs of ```MyRecommendation```,used the command ```sbt```then ```package```.It packaged the template,and  just simply going down the next steps.Everything is fine.

Answer (score 0):

You must remove .sbt folder so fixed this error.